# A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'. I am using Tflite in My Flutter Project its Throw an error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using Tflite in My Flutter app but this throws an error

[image]

I am trying to implement Tensor Flow in my project and during the build time in android its not working.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.
> No signature of method: build_cjzs76bmoa4s3xuisbd6iogry.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_cjzs76bmoa4s3xuisbd6iogry$_run_closure2) values: [build_cjzs76bmoa4s3xuisbd6iogry$_run_closure2@27fba1d4]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 2):

First visit this directory that is shown in the error
E:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle
There change the dependencies at the end to

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:+'
}
```

and save.If still it doesn't work try to change your minSDK version to 19. This should fix your problem :)

Comment: when i am adding this in my project in android\build.gradle
but its throw an error again